# PHP preg_replace with any variation of upper/lowercase?

Tags: preg-replace

I needed to write a custom module in drupal to help out with my location search. Initially I simply needed to remove a comma from queries, and then I realized that I would need to replace all instances of states with their abbreviation (California -> CA) because of how information is stored in my database. However, upon doing this I found out that my method of using preg_replace seems to be dependent on upper/lowercase. So in this line:

`$form_state['values'] = preg_replace("/alabama/", 'al', $form_state['values']);`

"alabama" will be replaced with "al", but "Alabama" or "ALABAMA" will not. Is there a way to replace any instance of Alabama with its abbreviation without accounting for every possible variation in casings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$form_state['values'] = preg_replace("/alabama/i", 'al', $form_state['values']);
```

The 'i' modifier will make the pattern case-insensitive.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much. Insensitive was the word I couldn't remember, which apparently made my answer impossible to find. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 6):

you can try also  **str_ireplace()** it's Case-insensitive

```
<?php
$str = 'alabama ,Alabama,ALABAMA';
$replace = str_ireplace('alabama','al',$str);
echo $str;
echo "<br/>";
echo $test;
?>
```